# Return value based on criteria (moving window, count))

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I tried to think of a formula to get the value for column C and D but not success. Please Help.

| Name | YYYYMMDD | Column C | Coumn D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Mary | 2023/1/1 |  |  |
| Mary | 2023/2/1 | 1 |  |
| Mary | 2023/3/1 | 1 | 1 |
| Mary | 2026/4/1 |  |  |
| Mary | 2026/5/1 | 1 |  |
| Mary | 2026/6/1 | 1 | 1 |
| Peter | 2021/1/1 |  |  |
| Peter | 2021/2/1 | 1 |  |
| Peter | 2022/4/1 |  |  |
| Peter | 2022/5/1 | 1 |  |
| Peter | 2025/6/1 |  |  |
| Peter | 2025/7/1 | 1 |  |
| Peter | 2025/8/1 | 1 | 1 |

**Column C criteria :**
Return 1 when there are 2 or more record for column A(e.g Mary) in the last 12 months in column B

e.g. Cell C3 return 1 because there are 2 records (2023/2/1 and 2023/3/1) for Mary in the last 12 months

**Column D criteria :**
Return 1 when there are 3 or more records for column A(e.g Mary)in the 12 months in column B

e.g. Cell D4 return 1 because there are 3 records (2023/1/1, 2023/2/1 and 2023/3/1) for Mary in the last 12 months

**Assumption for Column B:**

1: There is only 1 record for each person in each month
2: always the 1 day of each month

- expect a excel formula /array
- can be done in excel
- as easy to execute as possible
- Excel version: MS Excel 2016(16.0.5366.1000)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Assuming no Excel version constraints as per the tags listed in the question*, you can try the following in cell `F2`:

```
=LET(A, A2:A14, B, B2:B14, CALC, LAMBDA(p, MAP(A, B, LAMBDA(x, y, 
 LET(ref, EOMONTH(y,-12)+1, f, FILTER(B, (A=x) * (B>=ref) * (B<=y),0),
 IF(@f=0 ,"", IF(ROWS(f) >= p, 1, "")))))), HSTACK(CALC(2), CALC(3)))
```

Here is the output:
[image: output]

We define a user `LAMBDA` function `CALC` with an input parameter (`p`), to avoid repetition of a similar calculation.

For an older Excel version, you can try the following for column `F`

```
=IF(SUM(($A$2:$A$14=A2) * ($B$2:$B$14>=(EOMONTH(B2,-12)+1)) 
 * ($B$2:$B$14<=B2))>=2,1,"")
```

and drag the formula down. For column `G`, do a similar operation, and replace `>=2`with `>=3`.

Comment: Much appreciated for your effort @David Leal.

Unfortunately, my excel version is MS excel 2016, could you please provide a workaround?

Thank you so much and have a great day!